# Replace part of text with html text not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to replace matching keyword in text with same keyword but wrapped with `<span></span>`

```
example : This is the sample text to be searched
```

replaced text should be line

```
This is the <span class="match">sample</span>text to be searched
```

I am using following code but its not working

```cs
protected String getTitle(object title)
{
    string sTitle = title.ToString();
    Regex regex = null;
    string pattern = @"(\b(?:" + _Keyword.ToString().Trim() + @")\b)(?![^<]*?>)";
    regex = new Regex(pattern);
    sTitle = regex.Replace(sTitle, "<span class='keyword-highlight'>" + _Keyword + "</span>");
    return sTitle;
}
```

above code replace whole text with keyword not just the matching part

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
regex = new Regex(pattern);
```

With this:

```
regex = new Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I run this code:

```
string _Keyword = "Sample";
string sTitle = " This is the sample text to be searched";
Regex regex = null;
string pattern = @"(\b(?:" + _Keyword.ToString().Trim() + @")\b)(?![^<]*?>)";
regex = new Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
sTitle = regex.Replace(sTitle, "<span class='keyword-highlight'>" + _Keyword + "</span>");
```

and result is:

```
This is the <span class='keyword-highlight'>sample</span> text to be searched
```

Comment: I don't know :/

Comment: I think search is case sensitive, it works when i put the text in exact case as matching text

Comment: I updated my answer please check. 
I added regex options and problem solved.
regex = new Regex(pattern); --> regex = new Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be, you are getting some wrong value in 'sTitle'. Example: sTitle = "sample"

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the case of sample, you can use:

`regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`